# Custom Menu in UI - selection changes selection in drop down list

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I added a menu titled Reset Stats -> Inning Reset clicking this will change a few other items previously setup in my doc. I want the button to also change the selection of the dropdown menu to the number that is next in line. 1 - 2 - 3 - 4 - 5 - 6 - 7 - 8

1 - Menu selection of "Inning Reset"

[image: Selection Made "Inning Reset"]

---

2 - All options available on the dropdown menu and I want the dropdown menu to select the following number. So right now 1 clicking the inning reset would go to 2, if it was 2 clicking inning reset would go to 3 and so on.

[image: Selection Changes to the next number down]

---

Dropdown menu changes to the next item in line.

[image: Final Need]

Comment: Hopefully cleared it up.

Comment: Well, so in other words every time you click the custom menu 'Inning Reset' the value in the cell E3 should be changed with next value from the data validation list of the cell. Is it correct? I believe it can be done with a script. It doesn't look too difficult.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably something like this?

```
function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('Reset stats')
  .addItem('Inning Reset', 'inning_reset')
  .addToUi();
}

function inning_reset() {
  var cell = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('e3');
  var current_value = '' + cell.getValue(); // it should be a string!
  var dropdown_list = cell.getDataValidation().getCriteriaValues()[0];
  var next_index = dropdown_list.indexOf(current_value) + 1;
  if (next_index == dropdown_list.length) next_index = 0; // cycle
  next_value = dropdown_list[next_index];
  cell.setValue(next_value);
}
```

Every click on the custom menu `Inning Reset` it changes a value in the cell `E3` to the next value from its dropdown list: `1` > `2` > `3` > `4` > `5` > `6` > `7` > `8` > `1` > `2` > `3` ... etc